# Why does this compile, Template deduction should fail?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm attempting to write a serialiser. The following code compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class SpaceStream
{
public:

    SpaceStream(const std::string& filename)
    :
        m_file(filename)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value>::type
    Add(const std::string& key, const T& t)
    {
        m_file << key;
        m_file << ":{";
        t.Serialise(*this);
        m_file << "},";
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<T>::value && !std::is_reference<T>::value>::type
    Add(const std::string& key, const T t)
    {
        m_file << key;
        m_file << ':';
        m_file << t;
        m_file << ',';
    }

private:
    std::ofstream m_file;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> m_pointerObj;
};


class ISerialise
{
public:
    virtual void Serialise(SpaceStream& stream) const = 0;
};

class Test1 : public ISerialise
{
public:
    int m_x;
    int& m_rx;

    Test1(int& x)
    :
        m_x(x), m_rx(x)
    {
    }

    virtual void Serialise(SpaceStream& stream) const
    {
        stream.Add("x",m_x);
        stream.Add("xr",m_rx);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int j = 13;
    Test1 test(j);
    j = 23;

    SpaceStream ss("somefile.ss");
    ss.Add("testobj",test);
}
```

I'd have thought that this line:

```
stream.Add("xr",m_rx);
```

would have failed because of the two `Add` functions, one specifically checks that the type isn't a class, the other checks that it's not a reference. `m_rx` is a reference type, so it should fail?

**EDIT**
I understand now that the type is actually a value and not a reference. I need to be able to identify references so that I can keep track of them (I only want to serialise the data once, and reference it).

Comment: "*I need to be able to identify references so that I can keep track of them*" what do you mean ?

Comment: This is really no different than having a function `void f(int)` and calling it with a value that is a reference to `int`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with templates, the problem stays without them. A variable itself is always a lvalue reference (no templates) when passed as a function argument. Then, depending on your function signature, you either create an object (that becomes a copy)  (pass by value) OR create a lvalue reference that is bound to the passed reference. (pass by reference). But there is no way to specify at calling expression how do want to pass the argument. You cannot have `void foo(int);` and `void foo(int&)` simultaneously and call `int i = 0; foo(i)` since it is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

According to [expr#5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#5)

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression. [ Note: Before the lifetime of the reference has started or after it has ended, the behavior is undefined (see [basic.life]).  — end note ]

I think the argument type `A` will never be a reference type when performing template argument deduction. A simple test could be

```
#include <type_traits>    

template <class T> void f(T) { static_assert(std::is_same<T, int &>::value, "ERROR"); } 
template <class T> void ff(T) { static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "ERROR"); }   

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int i;
    int &r = i;
    f(r); // static assert failed
    ff(r); // static assert success
    return 0;
}
```

One walk-around I can think of is explicitly specify template argument using `decltype`

```
f<decltype(r)>(r); // static assert success now
```

Comment: *"I think the argument type A is never will be a reference type when performing template argument deduction"*, except for a forwarding reference type

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm not fully understanding your point. If you mean `std::forward`, there is no template argument deduction at all since we need explicitly provide the template argument when using it. As for forwarding reference type deduction, the `A` part still cannot be reference type.